# OpenPyxl Overlapping Data Labels (Bar Chart)

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl (this module is used over xlsxwriter because I need to access and write to a preexisting workbook) to create multiple bar charts. I have removed grid lines and the X / Y axis as well as added data labels. I have not been able to figure out how to make the data labels not overlap (without making the labels vertical). I am new to Python so any tips on formatting would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart,Reference
from openpyxl.chart.label import DataLabelList
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import CharacterProperties, ParagraphProperties, Paragraph
    axis = CharacterProperties(sz=550)
    rot = openpyxl.drawing.text.RichTextProperties(vert='eaVert')
    sheet = book['Graph Info']
valuesQT = Reference(sheet, min_col = 8, min_row = 3, max_col = 10, max_row = 11)
catsQT = Reference(sheet, min_col = 7, min_row = 4, max_col = 7, max_row = 11)
chartQT = BarChart()
#Formatting Code Start
chartQT.y_axis.majorGridlines = None
chartQT.x_axis.majorGridlines = None
chartQT.dLbls = DataLabelList()
chartQT.dLbls.showVal = 1
chartQT.dLblsPos='bestFit'
#chartQT.separator = True
chartQT.dLbls.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=axis), endParaRPr=axis)], bodyPr=rot)
chartQT.y_axis.delete = True
chartQT.type = "col"
chartQT.style = 10
chartQT.add_data(valuesQT, titles_from_data=True)
chartQT.set_categories(catsQT)
chartQT.shape = 4
chartQT.height = 6
chartQT.width = 12
chartQT.title = "  Change "
sheet = book['Summary']
sheet.add_chart(chartQT, "A1")

writer.save()
```

Comment: I don't know either. A lot of this stuff is not explicitly documented in the specification so some degree of patient reverse engineering from an existing file is required. But it looks like you're already trying this.

Comment: I have been scouring the documentation, your the mailing list, and here. I haven't been able to make much progress on this issue. Do you have any ideas you could point me to? Thanks again for your help. @CharlieClark

Comment: If you could post a sample file on the mailing list it would be easier.